# Possible bug with ads

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising

I've seen this ad appear on Stack Overflow.

[image]

I'm pretty sure that the number 10 `__default` book on Amazon is from another category.

#### Bonus Track

Make the title box larger. I'm yet to see one advertised book on Stack Overflow where its title is displayed completely.

---

Will SOFU ever have these kind of ads?

[Evony ads rock! XD http://images.lazygamer.co.za/2009/08/Evony4.jpg](http://www.lazygamer.co.za/general-news/a-history-of-evony-ads-the-insanity-continues)

Comment: Is it ironic that an ad question is asked by spam?

Comment: Why is it not the Evony ad?

Comment: Do you want me to change my name to `Eggs, Spam, Ham and Spam`?

Comment: @Eggs, Spam, Ham, and Spam: Yes. ;P

Comment: Happy now random? I offended Ólafur!

Comment: Offend away!

Comment: I never said I didn't like porn.... not saying I like it either :P

Comment: @Ólafur Waage: so you don't not like it?

Comment: I don't like it, or do I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the porn ad there. I don't think SOFU will ever have this. [Because of this blog post.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001286.html)

Comment: I know. Actually the linked article in the "Civ clone game ad" http://www.lazygamer.co.za/general-news/a-history-of-evony-ads-the-insanity-continues came up when I was looking for Jeff's post. I was just pleasing some random dude.

Comment: It's not pornography. It's falsely advertising pornography.

Comment: You took something someone said literally. Minus 1 internet for you.

Comment: You should add a pornography ad to show that you weren't completely serious.

Answer (score 0):

I love the new layout!

[It's cleaner now. http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/6206/soads.png](http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/6206/soads.png)

It's really cleaner now.